# How do I forward declare a class derived from a forward declared template base class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, forward, derived

I am trying to forward declare a class that is derived from a template class that must also be forward declared.

Here is an example of the classes:

```
class TType {
public:
    TType() { }
};

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base() { }
};

class Derived : public Base<TType> {
public:
    Derived() { }
};
```

Here is a failed guess at what I need:

```
class TType;
template<typename T> class Base;
class Derived : public Base<TType>;  // This fails
Derived* pDerived;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just forward declare the class name:

```
class Derived;
```

You can't include any more information about a class in its declaration; base classes, members, etc. can only be declared in the class definition.

This forward declaration can be used to do various things, including declaring pointers or references (such as `pDerived` in your example), and also declaring functions with `Derived` as an argument or return type. If you need to do anything that needs to know the class's size, base classes, or members, then you'll need the full definition.

Comment: You are of course right, but when I tried that and it failed. Here is my mistake, in the forward declaration I did `namespace { class Derived };` and then `class Derived;`.  Apparently using `namespace` to say something has no namespace is not the same as just skpping `namespace` so the compiler was telling me it was ambiguous.